# The difference between callback and just a function being called inside of another function

Tags: javascript, callback

Can someone please educate me on:

- What's the difference between a function being passed as an argument 
  `callback function` and a function being called inside of another
  function after some code is called?
- When should I use **each** scenario?

When should I use each scenario?

Please see my simple example below. Thank you for any help you can share.

```
   //func with callback passed as argument
function func1(name, fc1){
    fc1(name);
}

const printIt = (name)=>{
    console.log(name);
};

func1("samson", printIt);

//------------------------//

//func with a function called upon initial function being called. 
function func2(name1){
    //some code is called then printIt func is initialized
    printIt(name1);
}

func2('sammy');
```

Comment: the difference is, a callback function is passed as an argument to a function for it to call back, very common when dealing with asynchrony ... which one you use depends on which one is appropriate

Comment: "When should I use each scenario?" If you want the client of your function to be able to inject arbitrary behavior, use a callback. For example, a promise accepts callbacks for actions to be taken on rejection or resolution of the promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between a function being passed as an argument callback function and a function being called inside of another function after some code is called?

It's the same as any time you pass an argument instead of using a hard-coded value.

You can have some logic which is consistent, and add differences in the behaviour depending on the value you pass it.

This is simple:

```
function add_two_numbers() { return 1 + 2; }
```

This is flexible:

```
function add_two_numbers(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

> When should I use each scenario?

When you want either fixed or variable behaviour.